# Maximum number of integer points in a polytope

Tags: convex-polytopes, enumerative-combinatorics

What is the maximum number of integer points $\#M$ in a dimension $n$ closed bounded convex polytope $M$ given by $Ax\leq b$ with number $m$ of constraints and $O(d)$ bits in any entry of $A\in\Bbb Z^{m\times n}$ and $b\in\Bbb Z^m$? Can $\#M$ be $2^{2^{\omega(d)}}$ lattice points?

Comment: That seems way too big to me, but it's very possible I'm missing something.  Should the bound of $2^{\omega(d)}$ be obvious to me?